# Please ask for ... Bitte bitte um ...?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How to translate following?

> Please ask him for delay

I tried with

> Bitte bitte ihn um den Aufschub

Doubling *bitte* appears to be awkward. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: To double the bitte is absolutely ok for me. But it might be only my opinion.

Comment: Wouldn't it be "Please ask him for a delay." or "[...] to delay." ?

Comment: @bukwyrm, substantive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Sei so gut und bitte ihn um Aufschub.
- Bitte frag ihn nach einem Aufschub.
- Könntest du ihn um einen Aufschub bitten?

But the doubling does not appear as bad to me.

Answer (score 4):

Instead to try a verbatim translation you could paraphrase the message, e. g. like so:

> - Bitte frag ihn, ob er noch warten kann.
> - Bitte frag ihn, ob er mir noch etwas Zeit geben kann.